# I am defining my variable, but I am still having an error

Tags: java, calculator

I'm new to programming, and this program is working except with my `answer` variable. The program will not run unless I define it in line 8, even though I define it in the switch statement. The error is on line 32, and states,

> The local variable answer may not have been initialized.

Thank you in advance.

```
package learn;

import java.util.Scanner;

class calculator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double numberOne, numberTwo, answer;
        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        numberOne = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        numberTwo = input.nextDouble();
        String operation;
        System.out.println("Enter operation (Valid operations are add, subtract, multiply, and divide)");
        operation = input.next();
        switch (operation) {
        case "add":
            answer = numberOne + numberTwo;
            break;
        case "subtract":
            answer = numberOne - numberTwo;
            break;
        case "multiply":
            answer = numberOne * numberTwo;
            break;
        case "divide":
            answer = numberOne / numberTwo;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid operation");
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the way to ask a question. Please read [ask] and make a [mcve]. We can't help otherwise.

Comment: I prefer that you post your code here rather than having to go out to another link.  is it that much trouble?

Answer (score 0):

If The variable `operation` is not a valid option, then your switch is going to execute the  default option and than printing out the value of the variable `answer` which is not initialized...

Fix this by initializing the variable after you declare it.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get on line 32 self explain what you have to do to solve your problem: simply initialize the `answer` variable.

For example you should write:

```
double numberOne, numberTwo, answer;
answer = 0;
```

You have to initialize that variable because you don't use the variable `answer` anywhere in your code before the switch. Then if your code fall in the 'default' switch case the variable `answer` won't have any assigned value...so what will be printed out at line 32?